# How to generate a (magnific popup)-gallery without a-tags

Tags: magnific-popup

This is how the mark up looks like:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="container single sample00 odd">
        <img src="projects/sample00.jpg" alt="sample00.jpg" class="">
    </div>

    <div class="container single sample01 even">
        <img src="projects/sample01.jpg" alt="sample01.jpg" class="">
    </div>
    <div class="container single sample02 odd">
        <img src="projects/sample02.jpg" alt="sample02.jpg" class="">
    </div>
</div>
```

and that is what I thought would work:

```
$('.outer').magnificPopup({
    delegate: '.single',
    type: 'image',
    gallery: { enabled: true, }
});
```

I did a little trick by wrapping the images with a-tags and it work but it seems a bit clumsy to me.

Thanks.